# How do I do multiple updates in a single SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

I have an SQL query that takes the following form:

```
UPDATE foo
SET flag=true
WHERE id=?
```

I also have a PHP array which has a list of IDs. What is the best way to accomplish this other than with parsing, as follows, ...

```
foreach($list as $item){  
    $querycondition = $querycondition . " OR " . $item;  
}
```

... and using the output in the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would achieve the same thing, but probably won't yield much of a speed increase, but looks nicer.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE foo SET flag=true WHERE id IN (".implode(', ',$list).")");
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the IN clause (assuming your database supports it):

`UPDATE foo
SET flag=true
WHERE id in (1, 2, 3, 5, 6)`

Answer (score 5):

Use IN statement. Provide comma separated list of key values. You can easily do so using `implode` function.

```
UPDATE foo SET flag = true WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

Alternatively you can use condition:

```
UPDATE foo SET flag = true WHERE flag = false
```

or subquery:

```
UPDATE foo SET flag = true WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM foo WHERE .....)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use join/implode to make a comma-delimited list to end up with:

```
UPDATE foo SET flag=true WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever seen a way to do that other than your foreach loop.

But, if $list is in any way gotten from the user, you should stick to using the prepared statement and just updating a row at a time (assuming someone doesn't have a way to update several rows with a prepared statement).  Otherwise, you are wide open to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

you can jam you update with case statements but you will have to build the query on your own.

```
UPDATE foo
SET flag=CASE ID WHEN 5 THEN true ELSE flag END  
    ,flag=CASE ID WHEN 6 THEN false ELSE flag END 
WHERE id in (5,6)
```

The where can be omitted but saves you from a full table update.

Answer (score 0):

**VB.NET code:**
dim delimitedIdList as string = arrayToString(listOfIds)

dim SQL as string = " UPDATE foo SET flag=true WHERE id in (" + delimitedIdList  + ")"

runSql(SQL)

Answer (score 0):

If you know a bound on the number of items then use the "IN" clause, as others have suggested:

```
UPDATE foo SET flag=true WHERE id in (1, 2, 3, 5, 6)
```

One warning though, is that depending on your db there may be a limit to the number of elements in the clause. Eg oracle 7 or 8 (?) used to have a limit of 256 items (this was increased significantly in later versions)
If you do iterate over a list use a transaction so you can rollback if one of the updates fails